# How to give access an IAM Role access to an Elasticsearch domain in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I have an IAM Role for my Federated Identity Pool in Cognito. I want to give this role access to my Elasticsearch domain.

I added an inline policy to give read access to my Elasticsearch domain name using the new visual editor. I've attached this policy below.

I'm confused how to configure the access policy now for the Elasticsearch domain to give access to my IAM Role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "es:ListTags",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:domain/DOMAIN_NAME"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: I was still never able to figure this out. We also tried locking things down with a VPN but then we were not able to access services like Kibana.